# How do I query the code of a Stored Procedure in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm a college intern and have been asked to figure out how to query the code for a stored procedure in SQL. I only know a limited amount of SQL and have had trouble finding resources about this online. Does anyone know how you would write a query to do this?

I've looked at other Stack Overflow threads about this but all of them seem to be for legacy stuff or have mixed results

Comment: Does https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-view.html help?

Comment: Short search: Does this fit? [Show Procedure Code](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-code.html). Or do you need to query like `select * from procedureCode inner join otherTable where linenumber = 4 and contains(line, 'myvar');`

Comment: The term "stored query" not exists. Do you meanm a view? stored procedure? something else?

Comment: @Akina I assumed this meant `view` because that's how `view` is defined at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html

Comment: Edit: Yes, I meant to say "Stored Procedure", I made a typo. To restate my question correctly: I am trying to figure out how to get the code of a stored procedure via a SQL query

Comment: In that case, does https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-code.html help?

Comment: Hi Rich! as you discover better, more accurate language, please keep your title and question body edited to be accurate -- helps those that will come across it later.